# Sending Quotes through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, action, send

I have asked this question before but up till now, I still can't get answer.
I am creating an quotes App, that the quotes will be send to Whatsapp, imo, and this is my line of Code..

```
int selector;
Button previous, next, send;
TextView display;

//List of random quotes
ArrayList<String> listOfRandomQuotes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspiraionalquotes);


    listOfRandomQuotes = new ArrayList<String>();

    listOfRandomQuotes.add("Anger is the most important of passion. It affects nothing it touches and hurts the one who is possessed by it more than the one against whom it is directed.");
    listOfRandomQuotes.add("No one can give you better advice than yourself.");
    listOfRandomQuotes.add("The most wasted of all days is the one without laughter.");
    listOfRandomQuotes.add("The man who persist in knocking will succed in entering.");


setButtonOnLongClickListener(); 
    }

private void setButtonOnLongClickListener() {
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Need Help Here");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");             
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(i, "Can you Handle This");
            // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
            if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(chooser);
```

Now if the send button is clicked, the message that will be send it "Need help Here"...........All I want is the Quotes generated to be send.

2. I also want the preview button to be "BACK BUTTON" and not randomly select the Quotes...
   this is the code for the Previous Button...

   ```
       previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);

       previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Random randomnumber = new Random();
           selector = randomnumber.nextInt(277);
           display.setText(listOfRandomQuotes.get(selector));

       }
   });
   ```

Attached is the complete App Screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6KFa.png)